# Keyboard typing language is wrong

Tags: keyboard, language

My keyboard typing language is wrong.
I am facing problem in typing keyboard in Windows 10.
When I typed (Shift + 2) for **@**, then it was typed **"** and I have not found the button of \ or | on my laptop's keyboard.
I have searched about this problem on internet and found the language settings problem.
While Windows 10 installation, I have selected English(United Kingdom) instead of English(United States).
Now I can't able to change this language.
I need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a topic for SuperUser.

You can change your keyboard layout in Region and language settings. (options)

[image]

Then add a keyboard:

[image]